# Is there a way to export all AWS Security Groups to CSV? moreover, is there a recommended way of keeping track of SR changes?

Tags: amazon-web-services, security, aws-cli, security-groups, csv

We have a relatively small dev environment in AWS with about 50 Security groups with multiple permission entries. is there a recommended way of keeping track of SR changes, Access, etc?

My manager dont want to use AWS config (Price wise), so the only way i think of is to export all of the SR to a CSV file - how do I do that?

Thank you! : )

Answer (score 4):

AWS config at $0.003 per change is a trivial cost. It is likely to cost you FAR more to do this any other way. If you really want to do it the hard way you can use the [AWS ClI to export json](https://awscli.amazonaws.com/v2/documentation/api/latest/reference/ec2/describe-security-groups.html), parse that using some custom written software, and add the parsed data to some kind of data store.

A better way to approach this would be to define all your security groups in CloudFormation, version control it in git / CodeCommit and deploy using CloudFormation, and change IAM permissions so no-one or few people can change security groups in the console.

Answer (score 1):

You can do exports from the console. Here's [how](https://cloudly.engineer/2021/export-aws-security-groups-rules-to-csv/aws/).

1. Login to the AWS console, navigate to the EC2 service
2. Select Security Groups
3. Select the top most square checkbox
4. You’ll see a big dropdown button that says, “Export Security Groups to CSV“, simply click it!

Done, your CSV will automatically download.

Comment: WARNING: You can see for example: `Security Groups (50/73)`
It means you will only export 50 (not all)!!

Answer (score 0):

aws ec2 describe-security-groups --profile  --region  --query 'SecurityGroups[*].[Description,GroupId,GroupName,OwnerId,VpcId ]' --output text >> security-groups.csv